# I'm getting TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'hasNextPage' of '{}' as it is null when i try to build gatsby app with wordpress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, gatsby

success createSchemaCustomization - 15.101s

ERROR

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'hasNextPage' of '{}' as it is null.
at paginatedWpNodeFetch (D:\repos\esj-site\node_modules\gatsby-source-wordpress\src\steps\source-nodes\fetch-nodes\fetch-nodes-paginated.js:87:47)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at fetchWPGQLContentNodes (D:\repos\esj-site\node_modules\gatsby-source-wordpress\src\steps\source-nodes\fetch-nodes\fetch-nodes.js:44:26)
at D:\repos\esj-site\node_modules\gatsby-source-wordpress\src\steps\source-nodes\fetch-nodes\fetch-nodes.js:149:30
at D:\repos\esj-site\node_modules\gatsby-source-wordpress\src\steps\source-nodes\fetch-nodes\fetch-nodes.js:139:9
at async Promise.all (index 4)
at runFnForEachNodeQuery (D:\repos\esj-site\node_modules\gatsby-source-wordpress\src\steps\source-nodes\fetch-nodes\fetch-nodes.js:127:5)
at fetchWPGQLContentNodesByContentType (D:\repos\esj-site\node_modules\gatsby-source-wordpress\src\steps\source-nodes\fetch-nodes\fetch-nodes.js:148:3)
at fetchAndCreateAllNodes (D:\repos\esj-site\node_modules\gatsby-source-wordpress\src\steps\source-nodes\fetch-nodes\fetch-nodes.js:183:37)
at sourceNodes (D:\repos\esj-site\node_modules\gatsby-source-wordpress\src\steps\source-nodes\index.ts:55:5)
at runSteps (D:\repos\esj-site\node_modules\gatsby-source-wordpress\src\utils\run-steps.ts:41:9)
at runAPI (D:\repos\esj-site\node_modules\gatsby\src\utils\api-runner-node.js:434:16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to there not being an instance of a certain type in WP yet.  So if you have a Customer type in your schema, but no Customer entries in WP, you will see this error.  `pageInfo`, which contains `hasNextPage` is normally populated by WPGraphQL, but some plugins may filter it and return `null`.  This should be fixed in `gatsby-source-wordpress` 5.10.0. (PR [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/32369)).  Until then, you can [add that type to the exclude field in the options](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/docs/plugin-options.md#type__allexclude).